# Ошибка определения геопозиции: The Geolocation service failed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Хочу сделать, чтобы на простой html-странице определялась геопозиция пользователя, который на неё зашёл.
Для этого стал использовать Google Maps API. Делаю всё по [этому примеру](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation#try-it-yourself).

Вернее как делаю — просто скопировал и вставил к себе.
Файл находится в корне сайта index.html. Предварительно сгерерировал `API_KEY`.

В настройках указал

> Ограничение для ключа — HTTP-источники перехода (веб-сайты)
>
> HTTP-источники перехода (веб-сайты)
>
> ```
> *.site.com/*
> site.com/*
> site.com
> ```

И, как ни странно, ничего не работает...
В Firefox работает. Во всех остальных браузерх, пишет ошибку (и не только у меня):

> Error: The Geolocation service failed.

Подскажите, что я не так сделал? Куда копать?

Comment: У вас просто статический html файл  в который вы прикрутили google maps ? или все же есть веб сервер какой-то?

Comment: простой html файл, в нем код вставленный от сюда  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation#try-it-yourself

Comment: 1) - нужен веб сервер чтобы запускать страничку так http://localhost/простой.html 2) - добавить нужно http://localhost/ в google dev console

Comment: хмм, ну имеется в виду что у меня веб сервер

Comment: то етсь так сделано

site.com/index.htlm

Comment: в гугл google dev console

HTTP-источники перехода (веб-сайты)

*.site.com/*
site.com/*
site.com

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применит следующий код для создания карты Гугл с определением текущего местоположения и созданием направления/маршрута к определённому объекту (в моём случае - это форт Екеторп в Швеции). В этом коде вы можете редактировать следующее:

- zoom - приблежение и удаление показа карты
- MapTypeId - типы показа карт - **[инфо Гугл](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeId)**
- destination - координаты определённого объекта - **[как определить координаты](https://itouchmap.com/latlong.html)** (введите адрес)
- DirectionsTravelMode - вид/средство передвижения по маршруту - **[инфо Гугл](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes)**
- language= обозначение языка карты (установлен в линке maps.googleapis - вверху)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=de>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name=robots content=all />
<meta name=author content=https://plus.google.com/107237366663877426287 />
<meta name=description content="Karte zu Burg Eketorp" />
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=yes />
<meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=black />
<title>Karte zu Burg Eketorp</title>
</head>
<body style=background:#e6e6fa onload=initialize()>
<main>
<header>
<h1 property=name style=text-align:center;font-size:90%;font-family:Verdana;color:#2f4f4f>Burg Eketorp</h1>
</header>
<div role=application>
<div>
<div id=map style="border:.15em ridge #708090;height:30em"></div>
<div id="panel">
<div id="directions"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;language=de"></script>
<script>if (navigator.geolocation) { //Checks if browser supports geolocation
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {  //This gets the
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    //users current
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 //location
     var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); //Creates variable for map coordinates
     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
     var mapOptions = //Sets map options
     {
       zoom: 15,  //Sets zoom level (0-21)
       center: coords, //zoom in on users location
       mapTypeControl: true, //allows you to select map type eg. map or satellite
       navigationControlOptions:
       {
         style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL //sets map controls size eg. zoom
       },
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //sets type of map Options:ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRIAN
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map( /*creates Map variable*/ document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions /*Creates a new map using the passed optional parameters in the mapOptions parameter.*/);
     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
     var request = {
       origin: coords,
       destination: '65.791238, 21.657444',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     }); 
     
   });
  
 
   
 }</script>
<a href=https://plus.google.com/107237366663877426287 rel=publisher></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен

Comment: нужно защищенное соединение https

Comment: Да, разумеется, я забыл указать, что требуется сертификат SSL.